# Create GDAL dataset from scattered points in python

Tags: gdal, xyz, gdal-grid

I have a set of points in XYZ format.
As they are not gridded data (no guarantee), I want to use GDAL's algorithms to create a regular grid out of the scattered data points.

I created a minimal example below:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal, ogr

input_points = [(x, y, value) for x in range(15) for y in range (21) for value in [x + y]]

dx = 0.5
dy = dx 

x, y, z = zip(*input_points)
x_low_left = np.min(x)
y_low_left = np.min(y)

nrows = int((np.max(y) - y_low_left + dy) / dy)
ncols = int((np.max(x) - x_low_left + dx) / dx)
rotation_deg = 0.

# Create a new GDAL memory raster
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("MEM")
output_raster = driver.Create('', ncols, nrows, 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)

# Set the geotransform and projection 
output_geotransform = (
    x_low_left - np.sin(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg)) * dy * nrows,
    dx * np.cos(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg)),
    dy * np.sin(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg)),
    y_low_left + np.cos(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg)) * dy * nrows,
    dx * np.sin(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg)),
    -dy * np.cos(np.deg2rad(rotation_deg))
    )

output_raster.SetGeoTransform(output_geotransform)
output_raster.SetProjection(ogr.osr.SpatialReference().ExportToWkt())

# Use gdal.Grid to perform grid resampling
options = gdal.GridOptions(format='MEM', algorithm='invdist:power=2.0:smoothing=1.0:nodata=-9999.0')
output_raster = gdal.Grid('', input_points, options=options)
```

The output dataset is not meant to be written out to a file as the data is needed elsewhere.

When I run this code I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
in method 'GridInternal', argument 2 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
  File "test_gdal_grid.py", line 36, in <module>
    output_raster = gdal.Grid('', input_points, options=options)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: in method 'GridInternal', argument 2 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
```

I understand that the `input_points` variable is not the expected type, but I can't get my head around it.

I appreciate there are other python modules that perform spatial interpolation, but I'd rather use GDAL here.

Any advice on how to make this work please?

Comment: If you search through the tests for where they're calling `gdal.Grid()` it seems its expecting an OGR dataset, a filepath to one, or JSON: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/utilities/test_gdal_grid_lib.py